# Match the last bracket

Tags: c#, regex

I have a `string` which contains some text followed by some brackets with different content (possibly empty). I need to extract the last bracket with its content:

```
atext[d][][ef] // should return "[ef]"
other[aa][][a] // should return "[a]"
xxxxx[][xx][x][][xx] // should return "[xx]"
yyyyy[] // should return "[]"
```

I have looked into `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` and read up on [lazy vs greedy matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions), but I can't for the life of me get this one right.

Comment: [check](https://regex101.com/r/bZ9tP4/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex will work

```
.*(\[.*\])
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bZ9tP4/1)**

More efficient and non-greedy version

```
.*(\[[^\]]*\])
```

*C# Code*

```
string input = "atext[d][][ef]\nother[aa][][a]\nxxxxx[][xx][x][][xx]\nyyyyy[]";
string pattern = "(?m).*(\\[.*\\])";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

Match match = rgx.Match(input);

while (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/8QsofE)**

It may give unexpected results for nested `[]` or unbalanced `[]`

Comment: to include nested `[]` cases you do `.*(\[.*?\])` https://regex101.com/r/bZ9tP4/2

Comment: @dnit13 that can be done but it will not be correct either..e.g. `[][aa[bb]]`, you will get `[bb]` but according to me the output should be `[aa[bb]]` because its not the nested bracket that's last one..its just a perspective of looking though

Comment: @dnit13 i have added a modified version of your regex

Comment: yes its a matter of perspective indeed, since nested case is not mentioned by OP, it could be either one of them. :)

Comment: @rock321987 Thank you, it seems to be working. There is no need to support nested brackets. Can you make a short explanation to how it works? If I understand correctly, the pattern consumes everything up to the last bracket with `.*`, and then matches the last bracket. Is this correct?

Comment: @tahatmat exactly..you are absolutely correct..because `.*` is greedy it consumes(_not exactly like this because some backtracking is involved_) till last `[` and then find the contents till last `]`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could reverse the string using a function similar to this:

```
public static string Reverse( string s )
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse( charArray );
    return new string( charArray );
}
```

And then you could perform a simple Regex search to just look for the first `[someText]` group or just use a for loop to iterate through and then stop when the first `]` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

With negative lookahead:

```
\[[^\]]*\](?!\[)
```

This is relatively efficient and flexible, without the evil `.*`. This will be also work with longer text which contains multiple instances.

**[Regex101 demo here](https://regex101.com/r/bM8rH3/1)**

Answer (score 0):

The correct way for .net is indeed to use the regex option `RightToLeft` with the appropriate method `Regex.Match(String, String, RegexOptions)`.

In this way you keep the pattern very simple and efficient since it doesn't produce the less backtracking step and, since the pattern ends with a literal character *(the closing bracket)*, allows a quick search for possible positions in the string where the pattern may succeeds before the "normal" walk of the regex engine.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string input = @"other[aa][][a]";

    string pattern = @"\[[^][]*]";

    Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

    if (m.Success)
        Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
}
```